# Convert inner json object to string

Tags: java, json, spring

My entity class looks like this :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_programstrm_projstream")
public class ProgramStm_Projstrm_Model {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    @Lob
    @Column(columnDefinition="TEXT")
    private String programstrm;
    private int programstrmId;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH })
    @JoinColumn(name = "projstrmId")//
    private ProjectStreamModel projstrmId;
//getter and setter
}
```

Based on this entity I am getting result json like this

```
{
    "programstrm": "D-BSS Implementation",
    "programstrmId": 3,
    "projstrmId": {
      "name": "Program Leadership"
    }
  }
```

But I want ProjectStreamModel response as a string not as an object so that final result json looks like this"

```
{
    "programstrm": "D-BSS Implementation",
    "programstrmId": 3,
    "projstrmId": "Program Leadership"

  }
```

Comment: And what have you done in pursuit of this aim? Post your code.

Comment: Question modified....Is it sounds good?

Comment: Yeah, that is better. So you want to do it on the backend _before_ sending it to the client. If you have a way to configure your serializer on a per type level, you could do it that way. The simplest solution is to just create a new class to represent responses from the endpoint. The class will have the 3 fields in question as top level members.

Comment: Thanks a lot... it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

If I undestood right, using @JsonSerialize will probably help you (for example [link](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations))